# Error Iterating through a nested array in Javascript

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am looping through an array of objects and displaying the result in a table.

```
renderProducts(){
        return this.state.products.map((product, index) => (
            <tr key={product.id}>
                <td>{product.code}</td>
                <td>{product.name}</td>
                <td>{product.price}</td>
                <td>{this.renderVariants(product.variants)}</td>
            </tr>
        ))
    }
```

Now, `product.variants` is also an array of objects. So I need to loop through the array and assign to a variable. 
This is what this array looks like,

```
variants: Array(2)
0: {color: "red,blue"}
1: {size: "m,39"}
```

I want to loop through this array and show the result like this,
`Color - red, blue, Size - m, 39`. 
This is what I am trying to do -

```
renderVariants(variants){
        if (variants != null && variants.length > 0) {
            variants.map((variant, index)  => {
                for(var key in variants) {
                    var color = variants[key].color;
                    var size = variants[key].size;
                    var message = color+size;
                }
            });
        }else{
            var message = 'null';
        }
        return message;
    }
```

This only returns 'null' and returns empty for the color and size. 
How do I display the results the way I earlier said. Also, for example, the array may look like this too:

```
variants: Array(1)
0: {size: "t,u"}
```

So the result would be `Size - t,u`. How do I check if size, color is present before displaying their values?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simpler approach may be to reduce the object and map the array to a string like below.

```js
let variants = [{color: "red,blue"}, {size: "m,39"}];
let result = variants.map(obj => 
  Object.entries(obj).reduce((s,[key,val]) => s+=`${key[0].toUpperCase()+key.slice(1)} - ${val}`,'')); // creates a string of the required type
result = result.join(', ');
console.log(result);
```

```
renderVariants(variants){
    return variants && variants.map(obj => 
      Object.entries(obj).reduce((s,[key,val]) => s+=`${key[0].toUpperCase()+key.slice(1)} - ${val}`,'')).join(', ');
}
```

Comment: `join` would be more appropriate than `reduce` + slice off comma.

Comment: Without console.log(result), result is empty. It shows nothing on the table

Comment: you must return the result !

Comment: I am returning it. 
  renderVariants(variants){
        result = '';
        if (variants != null && variants.length > 0) {
            let result = variants.map(obj =>
                Object.entries(obj).reduce((s,[key,val]) => s+=`${key[0].toUpperCase()+key.slice(1)} - ${val}`,'')); // creates a string of the required type
                result = result.join(', ');
        }else{
            var result = 'null';
        }
        return result;
    }

Comment: Works. Changed 'let' to 'var'

Comment: let has block scope, so it cant be accessed outside the `if`

Comment: A better approach is to declare the `let result` outside the if..else

Comment: happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

Declare message variable outside if condition

```
renderVariants(variants){
      var message = '';
        if (variants != null && variants.length > 0) {
            variants.map((variant, index)  => {
                for(var key in variants) {
                    var color = variants[key].color;
                    var size = variants[key].size;
                    message = color+size;
                }
            });
        }else{
            var message = 'null';
        }
        return message;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could `map` on the array then merge each object entry then join the array

```js
const variants = [{
    color: "red,blue"
  },
  {
    size: "m,39"
  }
]

let v = variants.map(variant => Object.entries(variant).flat().join(' - ')).join(', ')

console.log(v)
```